# Why does my original copy of an object get replaced when it's deep cloned and not being modified?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a component the displays data and is updateable.

When the component loads it queries for data. When I get the results back I store a modifiable version in a variable and a deep cloned copy of the original data.

When I click cancel the modifiable data gets replaced with the original data. This works perfectly fine when I click edit, make a change, and hit cancel.

But if I click the save button, which actually doesn't save anything it just changes the form back to the view mode, click edit again, and click cancel my original data model somehow gets replaced as well.

[Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/HhBWvFUOF/2/edit)

Steps to reproduce

- Observe Original Value
- Click Update
- change value
- Click cancel
- Observe the original value is persisted
- Click update
- change value
- Click save
- click update
- click cancel

The expect behavior is that since Save doesn't actually persist any changes, the next cycle of update and cancel should restore it to the original value

Where does my `originalData` variable get changed?

Comment: +1 nice question

Comment: When loading the page i get "SecurityError. An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent."

Comment: What browser? @battery.cord

Comment: Chrome 75. I think its just something with the lightning playground, I'm getting it for both the question & answer.

Comment: hmmm I'm unsure. I'm using chrome 76

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a new simpler [Playground example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/JZVjTDd-Y/3/edit) to understand better.

> **Reason**:
>
> When you say `this.data = this.originalData`, it means you are
>   allocating same memory location to both `this.data` and
>   `this.originalData`. You are doing this on `cancel` in `toggleEdit`
>   method`

In the above playground link notice the usage of `this.data = { ...this.originalData }` in `toggleEdit` method. This will essentially clone the objects by allocating separate memory.

There is another commented line `this.data = this.originalData`.

Now, try editing and cancelling alternative by commenting/uncommenting above lines - you will notice the difference.

Comment: It's as clear as day once you finally notice it. This really took me for a ride. This is the second day you've helped me, thanks!